# Redirection in a Liferay portlet using response.sendRedirect

Tags: java, redirect, mobile, liferay, portlet

I am trying to port a mobile web application into liferay.  I have managed to port over most of the code, but the problem is that transistions keep going fullscreen.

I have read various postings on using portlet:actionURL and this seems to resolve to a much longer user with other parameters on it, but it throws my browser in a loop with a blank screen.

login.jsp

```
<form id="loginForm" action="<%= PortalUtil.getPathContext(request) + "/Submit" %>" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <label for="userid">User Number</label>
    <input type="number" name="userid" id="userid" pattern="[0-9]*" value="">

    <label for="userpass">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="userpass" id="userpass" value="">

    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" data-theme="a">Submit</button>
</form>
```

SubmitForm.java

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

@WebServlet("/Submit")
public class SubmitForm extends HttpServlet {
    public HttpSession getSession(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Do required initialization
        HttpSession session = null;
        session = request.getSession(false);
        return session;
    }

    // POST Method, Servlet contains NO GET Method
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = "";
        try {
            HttpSession session = getSession(request, response);
            String user = session.getAttribute("user");
            session.setAttribute("user", user);
            session.setAttribute("redirect", "Home");
            //session.setAttribute("redirect", "Status");
            //session.setAttribute("redirect", "Login");
            //session.setAttribute("redirect", "Error");
            response.sendRedirect("redirect.jsp");
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            System.err.println("ServletException:", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException:", e);
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

redirect.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
    String url = (String) session.getAttribute("redirect");
    System.out.println("redirect.jsp:url=" + url);
    if (null == url)
      url = "index.jsp";
    else
      session.removeAttribute("redirect");
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.location.href = "<%=url%>";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>status-jsp</servlet-name>
  <jsp-file>/status.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping><servlet-name>status-jsp</servlet-name><url-pattern>/Status</url-pattern></servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>home-jsp</servlet-name>
  <jsp-file>/home.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping><servlet-name>home-jsp</servlet-name><url-pattern>/Home</url-pattern></servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>login-jsp</servlet-name>
  <jsp-file>/login.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping><servlet-name>login-jsp</servlet-name><url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern></servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>error-jsp</servlet-name>
  <jsp-file>/error.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping><servlet-name>error-jsp</servlet-name><url-pattern>/Error</url-pattern></servlet-mapping>
```

new
redirect.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
    String url = (String) session.getAttribute("redirect");
    System.out.println("redirect.jsp:url=" + url);
    if (null == url) {
        url = "index.jsp";
    } else {
        session.removeAttribute("redirect");
    }
%>
<portlet:actionURL var="portleturl" >
  <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/portlet/<%=url%>"/>
</portlet:actionURL>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //window.location.href = "<%=url%>";
            console.log("${portleturl}");
            window.location.href = "${portleturl}";
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not completly sure i understand what you mean. but i think you mean to show a different jsp, if thats the question then in the doView method you can do this

```
final String jspurl = "/html/page/page.jsp";

                getPortletContext().getRequestDispatcher(jspurl).include(renderRequest, renderResponse);
```

That will render page.jsp instead of the jsp specified in portlet.xml for the current render

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be implementing some kind of simplified login in a servlet - as you mention Liferay: Liferay handles identity management already quite well, and I don't understand why you're creating your own on top of it. Further, you're implementing a servlet in a portal - this doesn't make a lot of sense. And when you create a portletURL (e.g. the actionURL) from a servlet's JSP, I'm not sure if all the necessary context for the portletURL are available in a servlet.

IMHO you should

- leave identity management to Liferay (or just don't use a portal when you want to reimplement the underlying infrastructure anyway)
- in case you stick with Liferay: implement your functionality in portlets and directly POST to the actionURLs instead of a servlet.

Liferay's documentation has several step by step instructions and documentations, e.g. [Learning Paths](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/learning-paths) and [Tutorials](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials)

Comment: I am not implementing this.  It is an existing application and the customer wants to "add" a remote Liferay portlet to utilize the same user database and access rights and functionality accessed.  I am trying to port this mobile app client into a Liferay portlet client.